# How do I unload an iPython extension that doesn't define how to unload itself?

Tags: ipython

I've loaded the `autoreload` iPython extension using:

```
In [1]: %load_ext autoreload
```

I want to unload it, but the following results:

```
In [1]: %unload_ext autoreload
The autoreload extension doesn't define how to unload it.
```

So, who can help me out here?

Comment: You can follow this guide to load/unload extensions in iPython : https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/